# Execute FireDAC connection editor at run time

Tags: delphi, database-connection, firedac

I would like to execute FireDAC connection editor at run time, but haven't found which class is the Component Editor for `TFDConnection`.

For example, it is easy to find out which class is the Component Editor for TADOConnection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can excute `FireDac` connection editor by calling `Execute` method of `TfrmFDGUIxFormsConnEdit` which you can find it in `FireDAC.VCLUI.ConnEdit` unit.

Here is an example how to do it:

```
Uses ... FireDAC.VCLUI.ConnEdit;

..

var FDConnEditor : TfrmFDGUIxFormsConnEdit;
begin
    FDConnEditor := TfrmFDGUIxFormsConnEdit.Create(Self);
    try
      FDConnEditor.Execute(FDConnection1,'Caption',nil);
    finally
      FDConnEditor.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Now you must use the `Driver ID` and it's parameters to work with DBMS, so you need to use drivers you need which you can find them in `FireDAC.Phys` unit, for example a `TFDPhysMSSQLDriverLink` in `FireDAC.Phys.MSSQL.pas`(MS SQL Driver), or simply drop them from `FireDAC Links` tab in the component platte.

Answer (score 4):

The editor form for FireDAC connections is `TfrmFDGUIxFormsConnEdit` located in unit *FireDAC.VCLUI.ConnEdit*. It provides a class method called `Execute` you can call with the connection as the first parameter.