# Cleaning up running FireDAC TTasks when closing application

Tags: delphi

I have a program (in Delphi 10.3) that allows the user to configure FireDAC database access at run time using the standard dialog as provided by the libraries (as listed in FireDAC help)

```
TfrmFDGUIxFormsConnEdit.Execute(DBConnection, '')
```

If the user exits shortly after doing this the program crashes with exceptions in `TFDPhysMSSQLDriver.GetServers`.  This is because that function launches a TTask to browse all the available MSSQL servers which takes quite sometime to complete and generates protection errors as soon as it tries to process any "progress" it has made after the rest of the application has shutdown.  Since this occurs in the FireDAC library I can't access the ITask handle for the task to wait for it and there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to wait for all outstanding TTasks to complete.

Does anyone know the approved method for either waiting for this task or all tasks to finish or what else I can do to "make safe" before exiting?

Comment: You should be instancing that and freeing it yourself. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234462/execute-firedac-connection-editor-at-run-time

Comment: Use via TfrmFDGUIxFormsConnEdit.Execute frees it but that doesn't do anything with the TTask which is left running and will feed the central FireDAC list of SQL servers as it completes so instancing the editor myself makes no difference

Comment: Not sure whether to make this comment and answer or not but it turns out that it all behaves just fine if you run it outside the IDE.  It doesn't really answer the underlying question but it means I don't need to fix it.

Comment: Usually that means the exception is handled by code without ill effect and the IDE grabs it before that happens. Been that way for a long time, ex https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32015  My comment was a guess since you didn't include what exception(s) was/were thrown.